# Store a string of hex into a char?

Tags: c++, ascii, cout

so I have a string that has a hex value in it. For example, my string may have

```
string a = "0x4D";
```

Would it be possible to assign **0x4D** to a **char**? Because I know that if I had

`char c = 0x4D` 
then I could print out its ASCII symbol, which would be **M**.

Is it possible to store **"0x4D"** into a char so that I can print out its ascii symbol? If anyone has any tips, that would be appreciated! If there's a better way to do this, please let me know! Thanks!

Comment: But originally the hex is in a string. Is there a way i can put that hex into a char?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `std::stoi` to convert the string to an integer (the base is auto-detected from the `0x` prefix):

```
std::string str = "0x4D";
char c = static_cast<char>(std::stoi(str));
std::cout << c << std::endl;
```

However, this is not guaranteed to give you the ASCII character for that value. There are various translations between character sets that occur in this simple code alone. For example, the `char`s in the string literal `"0x4D"` are initialized with the corresponding value in the implementation-defined *execution character set*. The printed character is also up to interpretation by the medium that is displaying it.

The best you could do is provide a mapping from ASCII values to characters. You could do this with an array where the index is the ASCII value and the element is the corresponding character.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `strtol` to convert the string to a number. You can then print this number or do other things you like with it.

Oh wait, you tagged it C++, and `strtol` is very much C-style. In C++, you can use a stringstream, and extract a number from it.

Answer (score 0):

To use stringstreams as Bas suggests:

```
int x;
string s = "0x10";
stringstream ss;
ss << hex << s;
ss >> x;
```

But I think it's a wasteful way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution based on `std::stringstream`:

```
std::istringstream iss ("0x4D");
iss.flags(std::ios::hex);
int i;
iss >> i;

std::cout << "[" << (char)i << "]" << std::endl;   //--> prints "[M]"
```